# Show RAM usage in numbers at the top panel?

Tags: raspberry-pi-desktop, monitoring

For things like CPU temperature or CPU usage, I could find plug-ins that show them in numbers. However, I could not find such a thing for RAM usage. The only thing I could find was Resource Monitor, which shows only a graph. The graph is too small that it is not easily readable. Is there any other way to display the RAM usage, in numbers just like the CPU usage?

[image]